# Using template file in custom module drupal 7

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

I have created custom module in drupal 7.  I have big html to print , that's why I want to create template file

my module code is here

```
function test_block_view($block_name = '') {

    $block['subject'] = t('test');
    $block['content'] = "";
    return $block;
}
function test_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'test' => array(
        'variables' => array('content' => "FOO"),
        'template'  => 'test', 
    )
  );
```

my file structure is here

[image]

but this code not working

Can anybody help me and tell why it does not print anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see where you used your theme function, you can try to render your theme function in block body

```
$block['content'] = theme('test');
```